# All letters in uppercase, but the first letter bigger than the other ones

Tags: fonts, formatting, small-caps

I want to know how can I achieve this effect in LaTeX:

[image]

Basically it looks like this: {F}IRST {L}ETTER, where the letters in the braces are a little bigger than the other ones but they all the letters are uppercase.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You are most likely referring to small caps:

```
\textsc{First Letter}
```

or

```
{\scshape First Letter}
```

Comment: What about trying to make first letter in uppercase smaller than the remaining uppercase letters? That is, the inverse of `textsc`? Looks trivial, though just asking if there is any.

Comment: @Werner Is there a way with another font and bold? I think this doesn't look that good to me and I need bold characters. Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: @SolidMark: `\textsc{fIRST lETTER}`

Comment: @thunermay: Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble and then you can use something like this: `{\bfseries F\scalebox{0.8}{IRST} L\scalebox{0.8}{ETTER}}`

Answer (score 3):

One can adapt expl3 code that egreg published in TUGBoat recently ([TUGboat, Volume 39 (2018), No. 1, pg.55](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121gregorio-expl3.pdf)).  Like Werner's solution using small caps, this solution assumes that the leading letters are entered as capitals. However, you can choose the size (and by extension other attributes)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\biglittlecap}{m}
{
\sheljohn_biglittecap:nn { #1 }
}
\tl_new:N \l__sheljohn_biglittecap_input_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sheljohn_biglittecap:nn #1
{
% store the string in a variable   
\tl_set:Nn \l__sheljohn_biglittecap_input_tl { #1 }
\regex_replace_all:nnN
% search a capital letter (or more)
{ ([A-Z]+ | \cC.\{?[A-Z]+\}?) }
% replace the match with \huge{match}
{ \cB\{\c{huge}\1\cE\} }   % <=== could use large, Large (or some other command...)
\l__sheljohn_biglittecap_input_tl
\tl_use:N \MakeUppercase{\l__sheljohn_biglittecap_input_tl}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\biglittlecap{\`Once \r{U}pon a Time}

\end{document}
```

[image]