# How can I get the same font in calling a procedure as it is in the definition of the procedure?

Tags: algorithmicx

I first tried this:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{procedure-f}{}
 ...
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Some other algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{procedure-g}{}
  \State $x \gets \textbf{procedure-f}()$
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

But the font in the call to procedure-f (in the code of procedure-g) changes.  I would have liked, for example, that the procedure call in procedure-g be in the same font as it was used in name of the procedure in procedure-f.  Maybe there's a macro that just applies the same font?

Comment: Use `\textsc{procedure-f}`...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [All letters in uppercase, but the first letter bigger than the other ones](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56332/5764)